# Hosting an Application Server on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm wondering if it is possible to host an Application Server on Google App Engine, I'm not planning to host a Web Application, but yes an App Server.
For example, hosting a Chat Server, that would Authenticate users log ins, register new users, establish a connection between two users running on clients developed to work with that Server.
If not, is there a similar service to GAE which I can use for that purpose.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) and [Channel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) APIs should let yo do it. If your client can make HTTP requests and your server can respond to them, then yes, you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

Have a look at the [Google Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) for an introduction to what the platform looks like and what APIs are available.  And crucially what restrictions there are.  For chat applications you might be interested in the Channel API.